# Compile maven project from Java

Tags: java, maven, compilation

In my java code, I want to compile a maven project (`mvn clean install`). How can I do it without making a `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`?

Comment: Which version of maven? 2.2.x or 3.0.x?

Answer (score 3):

Let's see...

```
$ which mvn
/usr/bin/mvn

$ cat `which mvn`
... lots of code ending with...
exec "$JAVACMD" \
  $MAVEN_OPTS \
  -classpath "${M2_HOME}"/boot/plexus-classworlds-*.jar \
  "-Dclassworlds.conf=${M2_HOME}/bin/m2.conf" \
  "-Dmaven.home=${M2_HOME}"  \
  ${CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER} "$@"

$ cat `which mvn` | grep CLASSWORLDS
CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER=org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
  ${CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER} "$@"
```

So I believe you need to run `org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(new String[] {"clean", "install"})`. YMMV.

Comment: Ok I have to find how to launch this!

Comment: Add libraries to you classpath and just run the line `org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(new String[] {"clean", "install"})`.

Comment: I'm searching maven dependencies :)

Comment: It's spelled out for you just above: `-classpath "${M2_HOME}"/boot/plexus-classworlds-*.jar`

Comment: I had : <dependency>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
 <artifactId>plexus-classworlds</artifactId>
 <version>2.4</version>
</dependency> but now is it possible to specify the path of the project to compile?